# Why Does Ichigo look different after he gets his soul reaper powers back?

Tags: bleach

Why in the fullbring arc he looks different when his powers are restored I mean his Zanpaktuou looks slightly different but his robe in normal and bankai state are different why is that? Also is Zangetsu still within him because Ichigo still has all the same abilities even after regaining his powers.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that it's because he retrieved his powers with the help of a lot of Shinigami who gave a part of their powers to create the sword Rukia used to reawaken him. But I'm not really sure it is the only reason actually.

And yes, Zangetsu is still within him, just keep forward into the manga, there is a lot to see about that subject.

Comment: Please include relevant sources/references.

Answer (score 0):

It never really says why, but i'm guessing it's because Kisuke had made him back into a soul reaper, and in doing so, nearly made Ichigo into a complete hollow. And, yes, Zangetsu is still within him.

Answer (score 0):

Gaining fullbring powers affected the form of his soul, so even though they were taken away, when he regained his soul reaper powers, the effects manifested in his bankai and his sword also changed.